# Where can I ask for non-computer hardware recommendations?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

I am looking for a good semi-professional heat press. I make custom t-shirts and bags for my business. I have been heat-pressing with an iron and the volume has got to a point where I want a machine.

Two sites have "recommendation" in the title: Software and Hardware. The Hardware Recommendations site is only for computer-related hardware. The DIY site has a "product-recommendation" tag, but seems mostly for home improvement.

Do recommendations on non-computer hardware belong in Stack Exchange?

Comment: See the [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) post about such things: [On proposals soliciting reviews, recommendations, comparisons, etc](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24050/122193) that says, "_I don't have any regrets with the sites we tried, but hardware and software search is about as far as we can take this format; we don't wish to keep expanding this model any further._"

Comment: I read it and it makes sense. StackExchange is about vetting information and finding a right answer; product recommendations do not fit that, and software and hardware recommendations are as far as StackExchange will go.

Comment: Some related questions: [Printing on Kydex Thermal plastic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/56680/126327) (on Graphic Design), [Building a heat press: Nichrome question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/204467/142621) (on Electrical Engineering), or your old question: [Heat press of vinyl on 100% polyester fabric](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/29109/14556) (on Engineering)

Comment: Thanks @Rob! GraphicDesign has a `hardware-recommendation` tag, so I posted it there: [Why the big price gap between heat presses at semi-professional ($300) and professional ($3000) ranges?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/159312/recommendation-of-a-semi-professional-heat-press). If recommendations are off-topic, I asked to understand the reason for the gap in prices.